# Tmux reloads Bash .profile

Tags: bash, tmux

Suppose I have this in my `.profile`

```
export VALUE=x:$VALUE
```

Then when I start a terminal and do

```
$ printenv VALUE
x:
```

the result is what is expected, i.e., `VALUE` is equal do `x:`.

Also if I keep launching bash like this

```
$ printenv VALUE
x:
$ bash
bash-3.2$ printenv VALUE
x:
bash-3.2$
```

the result is what is expected too.

However, if I start a terminal and launch `tmux` instead, I get

```
$ printenv VALUE
x:
$ tmux
$ printenv VALUE
x:x:
```

and the final `VALUE` is not equal do `x:`.

How can I launch `tmux` so that this does not happen, and it behaves like a fresh `bash` session?

I am on macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons why your `~/.profile` happens to be sourced more than once.

One would be that `tmux` is started in a way so that it behaves like a login shell.  As such, it will source the `~/.profile` naturally (see `man bash` at `INVOCATION`).  You can start `tmux` as a login shell by providing the option `-l`.  You didn't mention giving this explicitly, so I guess you didn't, but maybe it was implicitly passed to `tmux` by some alias or similar.  You might want to double check on this (enter `type tmux` for instance).

The more probable reason is that `tmux` just starts a shell which then assumes that it is a login shell and thus sources `~/.profile`.  This in a way is also correct, because starting a terminal muxer can be seen as the process of logging in.  More on this can be found here:  https://superuser.com/a/970847/153009

The third possibility (which was the reason in my case when I tried to reproduce your case) is that your `~/.bashrc` sources your `~/.profile` intentionally and explicitly.  Although this is against the original design, one finds this very often.  Obviously it often solves ugly issues with missing executions of invocation scripts.

You can check for this by giving out `${BASH_SOURCE[*]}` in the beginning of the `~/.profile` (redirect it to a file to be sure you can see it later).

Because of problems with this, I have the following script snippet in each of my invocation scripts (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc.):

```
(
    echo "$(date): .profile: $0: $$"; pstree -lp $PPID 2>/dev/null
    echo "BASH_SOURCE: ${BASH_SOURCE[*]}"
    echo "FUNCNAME: ${FUNCNAME[*]}"
    echo "BASH_LINENO: ${BASH_LINENO[*]}"
) >> ~/var/log/config-scripts.log
```

(Adjust the name `.profile` in the first line according to the script name of course.)

Comment: `-l` has no effect and is only there for compatibility. tmux shells are always login shells.

Comment: `type tmux` gives `tmux is /usr/local/bin/tmux`, and I do not have a `~/.bashrc`

Comment: So I believe I have to program my `.profile` to test if it is running in `tmux` context or not.

Comment: Somehow, tmux inherits the environment variables of the shell in which it is started, and it shouldn't. It should run the shell it creates as if this was run outside tmux. How can tmux start a shell clean of the environment variable settings of the shell in which the tmux command is run?

Comment: `-l` is recognized to support its use *as* the default login shell. The value of `default-command` determines which command to run in each new pane. If that command is an empty string (which it is by default), then each pane starts an instance of the shell specified by `default-shell` as a login shell.i

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no way to avoid tmux from starting its own shell without inheriting the environment variables of the shell where tmux is called. This means that startup shell scripts must take care if they are running inside tmux. For example, in bash, this can be done

```
if [ -n "$TMUX" ];
then
  echo Inside tmux
else
  echo Outside tmux
fi
```